Why does the execution order differ in Promise chains with return literal and return Promise.resolve?
I have problem in understanding the execution order of the following code snippet in JavaScript:
Promise.resolve('A0') // promise A
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A1
    console.log("Value of first A-chain-then:", value);
    return Promise.resolve("A1");
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A2
    console.log("Value of second A-chain-then", value);
    return "A2";
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A3
    console.log("Value of third A-chain-then", value);
  });
Promise.resolve("B0") // promise B
  .then((value)=>{ // onFulfilled B1
    console.log("Value of first B-chain-then:", value);
    return "B1";
  })
  .then((value)=>{ // onFulfilled B2
    console.log("Value of second B-chain-then:", value);
    return "B2"
  })
  .then((value)=>{ // onFulfilled B3
    console.log("Value of third B-chain-then:", value);
  })

The observed execution order is:
Value of first A-chain-then: A0
Value of first B-chain-then: B0
Value of second B-chain-then: B1
Value of third B-chain-then: B2
Value of second A-chain-then A1
Value of third A-chain-then A2

If change return Promise.resolve("A1") to return "A1", The observed execution order is:
Value of first A-chain-then: A0
Value of first B-chain-then: B0
Value of second A-chain-then A1
Value of second B-chain-then: B1
Value of third A-chain-then A2
Value of third B-chain-then: B2

Here’s my confusion:
When two chained Promise calls are executed, the onFulfilled handlers registered in each subsequent then should alternately be enqueued into the microtask queue. However, it seems that because Promise A returns a Promise.resolve('A1') in its first then, the chained calls of Promise A only begin after all the chained calls of Promise B have been fully executed.
The promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected) method returns a new Promise. When the onFulfilled function passed to then returns a literal value (value), the returned Promise will be resolved with Promise.resolve(value).
Based on this behavior, I would expect the following sequence of operations:

Excute Promise.resolve('A0') and add first then of promise A chain to the microtasks queue (current microtasks queue [onFulfilled A1])

Excute Promise.resolve('B0') and add first then of promise B chain to the microtasks queue (current microtasks queue [onFulfilled A1, onFulfilled B1])

Excute onFulfilled A1 , and its return value is a fulfilled promise. As a result, the second then of the Promise A chain is added to the microtasks queue (current microtasks queue [onFulfilled B1, onFulfilled A2])

Excute onFulfilled B1 , and its return value is a fulfilled promise. As a result, the second then of the Promise B chain is added to the microtasks queue (current microtasks queue [onFulfilled A2, onFulfilled B2])
...


According to my understanding, the result should be A0 B0 A1 B1 A2 B2. Why isn’t it like this? Is there something I might have missed about the difference between return Promise.resolve(value) and return value? Could someone please explain this? I would greatly appreciate any clarification!

When your .then() callback returns a Promise, the runtime will make the next .then() in your chain wait for the resolution of that Promise.

"its return value is a fulfilled promise. As a result, the second then of the Promise A chain is added to the microtasks queue" - no, it doesn't know (or want to distinguish) that the promise returned by the callback already fulfilled. It just calls .then() on it with callbacks that forward a fulfillment/rejection to the outer promise. This takes another tick of the queue.

@Bergi Thanks for your explanation! I got it!

@Pointy Thank u so much, your answer is spot on. I finally understand what you mean.

If you return a non-promise value, the promise is immediately resolved and the next .then() is immediatey scheduled in the microtask queue.
If you return a promise (like Promise.resolve('something')), the execution will wait until the returned promise is resolved. However, it doesn’t resolve immediately, so in this case .thens from the B promise would execute before the returned promise in A resolve and add the second .then to the queue.
Here is the example with even more "unexpected" behavior. See how "long" it took for the promise to resolve — Promise B managed to execute two .then() calls, just like in your example, where this wasn’t very noticeable as there were only two.


Promise.resolve('A0') // promise A
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A1
    console.log("onFulfilled A1:", value);
    return Promise.resolve("A1");
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A2
    console.log("onFulfilled A2", value);
    return "A2";
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A3
    console.log("onFulfilled A3", value);
    return "A3";
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A4
    console.log("onFulfilled A4", value);
    return "A4";
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A5
    console.log("onFulfilled A5", value);
    return "A5";
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled A6
    console.log("onFulfilled A6", value);
  })


Promise.resolve("B0") // promise B
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled B1
    console.log("onFulfilled B1:", value);
    return "B1";
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled B2
    console.log("onFulfilled B2:", value);
    return "B2"
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled B3
    console.log("onFulfilled B3:", value);
    return "B3"
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled B4
    console.log("onFulfilled B4:", value);
    return "B4"
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled B5
    console.log("onFulfilled B5:", value);
    return "B5"
  })
  .then((value) => { // onFulfilled B6
    console.log("onFulfilled B6:", value);
  })



You can also visualize the event loop in action here to see how the queue behaves live.

I’m a bit confused about step5 & step6. If the microtask queue follows the rule 'FIFO' , why does it appear that onFulfilled A2 is always pinned at the front? Could you please clarify how this works behind the scenes?

"When .then() returns a value or a fullfilled promise it creates a new promise." - no. Or it's unclear what exactly you mean.

Your steps 4 and 5 are wrong. You arrive at a microtask queue of [onFulfilled A2, onFulfilled B2], but then you state that they get executed in a different order. This makes no sense.

my apologies, I got a bit lost in it myself. I’m updating answer with a simple explanation and an example, I hope it adds more clarity to the topic
